# jquery replace string from text() with unknown characters

Tags: jquery, string, text, replace

I want to replace, to add some string in a text var in order to "wrap" my content, then to append it later.

For example I have this in my string var (in my var there isn't line break):

```
[th_section type="boxed" bgcolor="" txtcolor=""]
[th_header type="h1" txtalign="txt-left" subtitle="essai subtitle" txtcolor=""]
HEADER 1
[/th_header]
[th_five_sixths txtalign="txt-left" boxed="" last_column="true"]
[th_header type="h5" txtalign="txt-left" subtitle="" txtcolor=""]
100% Responsive Design
[/th_header]
Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna et. Quisque euismod orci ut et lobortis aliquam.
[/th_five_sixths]
[/th_section]
```

And I want to replace/add p tags like this :

```
<p>[th_section type="boxed" bgcolor="" txtcolor=""]</p>
<p>[th_header type="h1" txtalign="txt-left" subtitle="essai subtitle" txtcolor=""]</p>
<p>HEADER 1</p>
<p>[/th_header]</p>
<p>[th_five_sixths txtalign="txt-left" boxed="" last_column="true"]</p>
<p>[th_header type="h5" txtalign="txt-left" subtitle="" txtcolor=""]</p>
<p>100% Responsive Design</p>
<p>[/th_header]</p>
<p>Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna et. Quisque euismod orci ut et lobortis aliquam.</p>
<p>[/th_five_sixths]</p>
<p>[/th_section]</p>
```

In fact, I search how to regex like this maybe:

```
$someDiv.replace('[th_*******]', '<p>[th_*******]</p>').replace('[/th_*******]', '<p>[/th_*******]</p>')
```

I don't know what is the right way to use replace in this case. Name between bracket can be different except for [th_...] and [/th_...]
Maybe I need to use a function different than replace, I really don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *really* bad at regex but I think this should work:

```
theString.replace(/\]([^\[]+)/g, function(m) {
   return "]<p>" + m.slice(1) + "</p>";
}).replace(/(\[.*?\])/g, "<p>$1</p>");  // /(\[\/?th_[^\]]*\])/g
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujVrD/

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Can you just explain me a little bit the process of this regex. I'm very not familiar with this kind of things...

Comment: @lolo You are welcome, the first `.replace()` call replaces all the characters between `] ... [`. The second one replaces everything starts with `[` and ends with `]` with the second argument, `$1` refers to the matching string between the `(...)` in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Might I direct you to [jQuerys `.wrap()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/). It takes your selected elements and wraps them with a tag that you define in the methods first argument. In your case this would be `.wrap('<p></p>')`. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I can't wrap it because it comes from a string var. I don't want to wrap into the DOM. I want to put div container children text in a var then replace some string...